# React setState doesn't update with synchronous activity

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the below scenario Im updating the 'totals' state using a function call (sync) and updating the state. Then i append that state to an Object. But still the totals state doesn't update. But no effect on the state. Only the initial valued are returned.  I tried adding a useEffect with the 'totals' dependancy it get fired with the new values. But the state is not updating and persisting in the 'totals' state.I could do a small work around but I'm curious for the reason for this. Thanks

```
const [totals, setTotals] = useState({
    totalCODCost: 0,
    totalCODDeliveryCost: 200.0,
    totalDeliveryCost: 200.0,
    totalPrepaidCash: 0,
    totalPrepaidBankDeposit: 0,
    totalJobCost: 200.0,
    totalDue: 200.0,
  });

//no async operation here. Just iteration through a list of objects and getting a calculated value. Then updating the state
const generateTotalValues = (pickupDtoList: PickupDto[]) => {
    let totalCODCost = 0;
    let totalCODDeliveryCost = 0;
    let totalDeliveryCost = 0;
    let totalPrepaidCash = 0;
    let totalPrepaidBankDeposit = 0;
    let totalJobCost = 0;
    let totalDue = 0;

    pickupDtoList.forEach((pkg:PickupDto) => {
      totalCODCost += pkg.cost;

      if (pkg.paymentType === "COD") {
        totalCODDeliveryCost += pkg.deliveryCost;
      }

      totalDeliveryCost += pkg.deliveryCost;
      totalPrepaidCash += pkg.prepaidCash;
      totalPrepaidBankDeposit += pkg.prepaidBankDeposit;
      totalJobCost += pkg.packageTotal;
      totalDue += pkg.chargesDue;
    });

    setTotals({
        totalCODCost,
        totalCODDeliveryCost,
        totalDeliveryCost,
        totalDue,
        totalJobCost,
        totalPrepaidBankDeposit,
        totalPrepaidCash
    })
}


//Bug Is here
const submitDataSet = (pickupData:[]) => {
  generateTotalValues(pickupData);

   //Here the totals useState returns the old object eventhough i have updated in the above generateTotalValues. No async activties are done
   const obj: JobDto = {
      totalCODCost: totals.totalCODCost,
      totalCODDeliveryCost: totals.totalCODDeliveryCost,
      totalDeliveryCost: totals.totalDeliveryCost,
      totalPrepaidCash: totals.totalPrepaidCash,
      totalPrepaidBankDeposit: totals.totalPrepaidBankDeposit,
      totalJobCost: totals.totalJobCost,
      totalDue: totals.totalDue,
    };
  
  //previous state is returned. Not the newly updated values
  console.log('totals ====>', totals);

}
```

Comment: State updates in React are asynchronous, it will be updated at the next render.

Comment: @palindrom as setTotals update the state and makes a render, Won't the state get updated?

Answer (score 0):

`setTotals` is not a sync process. Since you console log immediately after your calculate function, state is not being updated at that point.

I suggest you to use useEffect with `[pickupData]` dependency (your form values) and calculate every time it changes. By the time you submit, the state will already be updated correctly:

```
useEffect(() => {
    generateTotalValues(pickupData);
}, [pickupData]);
```